# Definition of $n$ and $(n-1)$-dimensional volume of a Submanifold of a Riemannian Manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry, volume, geometric-measure-theory

I want to read the statement and proof of the co-area formula for Riemannian manifolds given in Isaac Chavel's *Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry* (pg. 85).

Assume all the manifolds we talk about are compact.

The section begins with the following:

> Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold.
>   In all that follows, we let $V()$ denote the $n$-dimensional volume of submanifolds of $M$, and $A()$ denote the $(n-1)$-dimensional volume.

**I don't know** what is meant by the $n$-dimensional and the $(n-1)$-dimensional volumes of a submanifold of $M$.

I could guess the definition of the $(n-1)$-dimensional volume of an $(n-1)$-dimensional orientable submanifold $N$ of an orientable Riemannian manifold $M$: Since $N$ is itself a Riemannian manifold after borrowing the metric from $N$, and since $N$ is orientable, it has its own Riemannian volume form, and thus it has a volume.

But it seems that the author has a more general notion in mind. I flipped through the book but could not spot the definition. I also tried googling but couldn't find anything.

Comment: He means that $V(\Omega)$ is the volume of a (compact) $n$-dimensional submanifold $\Omega$ with boundary,  and $A(X)$ is the "surface area" of a (compact) hypersurface $X$. If $\omega$ is the volume $n$-form of $M$, you get the area $(n-1)$-form of $X$ by taking $\iota_\nu\omega$, where $\nu$ is the unit outward normal of $X$.

Comment: Thanks. So the $n$-dimensional volume is defined for $n$-dimensional submanifolds and the $(n-1)$-dimensional volume is defined for $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifolds.  Is that right? (The orientability assumptions are implicit I guess?)

Comment: It's not clear what is meant by the unit *outward* normal. Did you mean to write just "unit normal"?

Comment: I was assuming orientability. You can do volume by integrating a density, but don't worry about these technicalities yet.